# Android application built in eclipse for 2.3 will it work in 2.2?

Tags: android, build

I've built an Android application in eclipse. Before starting the project I selected the 2.3.3 api. The code is very basic.

A friend of mine asked to have a copy, but he's using 2.2, do I have to rebuild the project in 2.2 or will it work just fine if I send him the APK build with the 2.3.3 api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion=.... />
```

in the android manifest to

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Project Build Target to 2.2, in the Properties Menu of your project in the Android drill down.

You should only get errors if you used methods that were introduced with the level 10 API (Android 2.3.3). Since you pointed out that your application is very basic, I highly doubt you'll run into major problems.

Comment: Then, after it builds clean, feel free to set your target back up again.  But do set minSdkVersion.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html)

> Selecting a platform version and API Level
>
> When you are developing your application, you will need to choose the platform version against which you will compile the application. In general, you should compile your application against the lowest possible version of the platform that your application can support.
>
> You can determine the lowest possible platform version by compiling the application against successively lower build targets. After you determine the lowest version, you should create an AVD using the corresponding platform version (and API Level) and fully test your application. Make sure to declare a android:minSdkVersion attribute in the application's manifest and set its value to the API Level of the platform version.

So in short, you'll have to recompile it

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the properties for your project and then select the Android dialog, you can change the API which your project is using. Provided you have have it installed.

Answer (score 0):

In the AndroidManifest file set android:minSdkVersion to 7.  In this way you force it to run in compatibility mode on devices that have lower version than the target mode(which is 8 in your case).